# PAM LDAP connect and bind flow

Tags: ldap, pam

Im managing a very strange case and I need a help from an expert on PAM Ldap.

My architetture is:

Linux (LDAP CLIENT) -> ODSSE (LDAP SERVER) -> ACTIVE DIRECTORY

The ODSEE is configured to perform a pass-through authentication (PTA) towards AD when the bind is requested by an user with the dc=users,dc=com suffix.

The ODSEE baseDN is dc=central,dc=com (It's a posix database - Rfc2307)
The AD baseDN is dc=users,dc=com

I'd like to perform authentication on AD and retrieve the profile user from ODSEE.

On my ldap.conf I set the user/passw and the PTA succeeds with success but on my Unix logs I receive user unknown.

I believe that the first connect with user/passw hardcoded on ldap.conf is going well but the second bind with my user retrieved from ODSEE / password is failing.

Is there a way I can see/track the entire content of this bind?
Does anybody here face some identical case?
Any help is welcomed.

Thank you
Daniel